# How to create a non-dynamic copy of a sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a sheet and rename based on cell value.

How do I create a non-dynamic copy? I need it to be more of a screenshot so all values stay the same. The idea being I can make many still copies and edit the main sheet.

The code I have makes a dynamic copy that changes when the main does.

How would I edit this code so it is gives still image copies?

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wh = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
If wh.Range("W13").Value <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Name = wh.Range("W13").Value
End If
wh.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want formulas to be changed to their values?

Comment: Also, typo - you have `Dim ws as Worksheet` but then use `wh` for the rest of the code.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the typo - no so I need VBA code so that the copies made are not linked to the main sheet - all the values on the copies will stay the same even if i make changes to the main sheet

Comment: Copy all and paste values on the "copy" sheet, or do a value transfer, set the value of the used range of the sheet equal to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two people have suggested copy and pasting special values. This adds an operation of moving the data to your clipboard, which is an external buffer outside of Excel. This has the side effect of clearing the users clipboard. If they had copied something it would now be lost.

This is faster and doesn't destroy the clipboard:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim oldSheet As Worksheet
    Set oldSheet = ActiveSheet
    oldSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set newSheet = ActiveSheet
    If oldSheet.Range("W13").Value <> "" Then
        newSheet.Name = oldSheet.Range("W13").Value
    End If   

    With newSheet.UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Addition of these lines will help:**

```
With ActiveSheet
    .UsedRange.Copy
    .UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

You can make use of the `Range.Pastespecial` property of Range Class

**Full Code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
ws.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

With ActiveSheet
    .UsedRange.Copy
    .UsedRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

If ws.Range("W13").Value <> "" Then
ActiveSheet.Name = ws.Range("W13").Value
End If
ws.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All you are missing is to copy data and paste them as values

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wh = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
If wh.Range("W13").Value <> "" Then
ActiveSheet.Name = wh.Range("W13").Value
End If
With ActiveSheet.Cells
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .Range("A1").Select
End With
wh.Activate

End Sub
```